# How to integrate Phonegap Camera with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, cordova, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for integrating the phonegap camera with AngularJS.  The first method I tried was creating a factory with promises that gets called from ng-click. Another way would be putting the code right inside the ng-click within the controller, but then it isn't reusable. Maybe a directive could be made from this? I'm sure there's a few other ways as well.  What would the "angularjs" way be?

Here's an example of the factory method that I tried....

The HTML:

```
<button ng-click="takepic">Take Picture</button>
```

The controller:

```
function picturePageCtrl($scope, Camera) {
    $scope.takepic = function() {
        // I'd like to push this into an array of "pics" here.
        // but it is hard to push() with promises.
        Camera.getPic();
    }
}
```

The factory:

```
.factory('Camera', function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return {
        getPic: function() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(
                function (imageURI) {
                    deferred.resolve(imageURI);
                },
                function (message) {
                    deferred.reject(message);
                },
                {
                    quality: 50, 
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I would place the logic in a directive, since it will need to access DOM functions (and directives are better suited for that). If you use `require: 'ngModel'` in your directive, you can use it to store the output value.

**Html:**

```
<button camera ng-model='myPicture'>Take Picture</button>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('camera', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
         elm.on('click', function() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI) {
               scope.$apply(function() {
                  ctrl.$setViewValue(imageURI);
               });
            }, function (err) {
               ctrl.$setValidity('error', false);
            }, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }
         });
      }
   };
});
```

In your **controller**, you can `$watch` the model and push it into an array:

```
$scope.myPictures = [];
$scope.$watch('myPicture', function(value) {
   if(value) {
      myPictures.push(value);
   }
}, true);
```

Comment: There's a ")" missing after "FILE_URI }" but it still doesn't pull up the camera for me.  Do I need to include "camera" in my controller?  That said, this is exactly the DRY method I figured was possible.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Okay, didn't see the on() function being used.  I didn't have jQuery included, but after adding 1.9, this works like a charm.  I'm still a little confused about the final part of the question - which is the best way to push the result to an array, but this definitely is the answer!

Comment: Just use $watch in your controller and push it into an array (see updated answer). In that case you will need probably need to use $apply when setting the viewValue.

Answer (score 3):

I added in a few options and corrected the code for other who come across this post like I did. Thank you for your post asgoth!

```
app.directive('camera', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {


         elm.on('click', function() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI) {
               scope.$apply(function() {
                  ctrl.$setViewValue(imageURI);
               });
            }, function (err) {
               ctrl.$setValidity('error', false);
            }, { 
                quality : 50,
                destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                allowEdit : true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 1000,
                targetHeight: 1000,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false 
            })
         });  
      }
   };
});
```