# Update image source (ng-src) with phone camera or library picture

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, mobile, typescript

In the view, there's an image tag:

```
<img id="profile-photo" ng-src="{{uri}}"/>
```

In the controller, I set a initial image source:

```
$scope.uri = 'test.jpg';
```

The user can select a picture from his library or take a photo to replace the initial image source:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture((uri: string) => {
    var image = <HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('profile-photo');
        image.src = uri;
        //$scope.uri = uri;
        //$scope.$apply();
    }, (error: string) => {
        console.error(error);
}, options);
```

This works as expected; the initial image is replaced by the new one. However, I'd like to do it "the angular way" and trigger the replace by updating $scope.uri instead of setting image.src directly.

But if I comment out the first line in the callback and uncomment the two following lines to do just that, I get an 404 error for the new image source, even though $scope.uri == image.src!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you tried `$scope.apply()` but did you try wrapping `$scope.uri = uri` in apply?

Comment: Plz chek if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548567/how-to-integrate-phonegap-camera-with-angularjs

Comment: @Ronnie: You mean like this: `$scope.$apply(() => { $scope.uri = uri; });`? Same problem. Tried wrapping it in a $timeout, too.

Comment: @RahulNaik: From what I understand, they use a directive and $setViewValue to update the image source. Why would that work but updating it in the controller doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh!

It was something completely different - I had to explicitly whitelist the file and content protocols:

```
module.config( function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|content):/);
})
```

It works now. Thank you for your suggestions!